# Set a bit flag with bitwise operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation

The following stored procedure sets a specific bit flag in a bit array of flags.
Is there any way to do it with out the `IF`?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SETFlag]
    @CMCONID int, @FlagID int, @FlagValue bit
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @FlagValue = 0 
        Update CMContracts
        SET Conditions = Conditions & ((POWER(2,30)-1) ^ POWER(2,@FlagID))
        Where ID = @CMCONID 
   ELSE IF @FlagValue = 1
       Update CMContracts
       SET Conditions = Conditions | POWER(2,@FlagID)
       Where ID = @CMCONID 
END
```

Comment: This may be a settled design for some reason but usually, despite the "neatness" or "compactness" of a bit-field design, it's better to expand out the data and model it relationally. I.e. with the current design, there's no real way to benefit from e.g. indexes if you need to *query* against this bit-field data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`IIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213574.aspx) instead, but im not sure there's much of a difference except requiring you to repeat the rest of the `UPDATE` query.

```
Update CMContracts
SET Conditions =  IIF(@FlagValue = 1, 
                        Conditions | POWER(2,@FlagID),  -- true
                        Conditions & ((POWER(2,30)-1) ^ POWER(2,@FlagID)) -- false
                     )
Where ID = @CMCONID
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep:

```
Update CMContracts
  SET Conditions = CASE WHEN @FlagValue = 0 THEN Conditions & ((POWER(2,30)-1) ^ POWER(2,@FlagID))
                   CASE WHEN @FlagValue = 1 THEN Conditions | POWER(2,@FlagID)
Where ID = @CMCONID
```

I may be answering your question too literally - perhaps your question was whether you could combine the two branches into a single expression with bitwise operators without a CASE. I'm afraid I don't have enough experience with bitwise functions to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`Case Statement`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to simulate `IF - Else` statement

```
  UPDATE CMContracts
  SET    Conditions = CASE
                        WHEN @FlagValue = 0 THEN Conditions & ( ( Power(2, 30) - 1 ) ^ Power(2, @FlagID) )
                        WHEN @FlagValue = 1 THEN Conditions | Power(2, @FlagID)
                      END
  WHERE  ID = @CMCONID
```